# Raspbmc does not seem to do anything

Tags: raspbmc

I have installed raspbmc and it seems to work. It has an IP address, I can ssh into it and ping the outside word from there, it updates the OS when it starts up, I can see the screen on the TV.  I am hoping to use it to view sites like netflix and filmon.

The problem is that I get a message telling me that the PVR manager has been enabled without any enabled PVR add-on.  I have tried enabling several from the list in add-ons but then all I get is a message "clientname pvr client failed to connect to  clientname backend.

When I go to the home screen and select Live TV >TV channels nothing happens apart from a message that "no pvr clients have been started yet"

There is something obvious and fundamental that I have missed :(

Comment: stackexchange.com & stackoverflow.com share a common login system. you can register once with a login & password, and then register any subject you like. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/ for info about the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, I did miss something fundamental :(

It seems that very early in my RPi experience I ticked the box in the settings labelled "Live TV" as the main reason I want xbmc is to watch live UK TV via iPlayer or Filmon.  This gave me an option of Live TV in the main menu.

So that is where I went when I wanted to watch live TV and nothing happened.

It is not very intuitive but what I must do is go to the main menu and select Videos then add-ons and click what I want (the right add-ons must already be installed).

Answer (score 2):

XBMC (the media center component that makes up raspbmc) requires a PVR server to stream from.

So the error message you are receiving regarding the PVR is either because you dont have a PVR server/backend, or you have not configured the client in XBMC correctly.

See this page for a bit more context:
[XBMC Wiki - PVR](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=PVR)

For Netflix and Filmon you will have to install an addon to use these services, as XBMC does not support them out of the box.

Netflix currently uses Silverlight (a Microsoft version of Flash), which does not work on Linux, and as raspbmc is based on linux, there is currently no easy way to view Netflix on the Raspberry Pi.

See this topic for more info reagarding Netflix on the Raspberry Pi: [How to stream Netflix on Raspbmc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/how-to-stream-netflix-on-raspbmc)