# Netflix on the Pi with XBMC -- any improvements?

Tags: kodi, streaming-video

According to the older questions

- [How to stream Netflix on Raspbmc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/how-to-stream-netflix-on-raspbmc) (January 2013)
- [Is there any workaround for Netflix compatibility?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/434/is-there-any-workaround-for-netflix-compatibility) (June 2012)

there was, at the time, no feasible way to view Netflix (and, I assume, Amazon Instant video and similar) content on the Pi, or on any Linux since they use(d) Silverlight (duh).

A German resident, I have no Netflix yet (but [may become one](http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/wireStory/netflix-coming-germany-france-markets-23805770)) and constantly evaluate upcoming ways to watch current series and movies legally. Now, I found

- [NetfliXBMC](http://lifehacker.com/netflixbmc-brings-a-better-remote-controlled-netflix-t-1484237283) and
- [news that Mozilla may support HTML5 DRM](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2344972/mozilla-grudgingly-brings-netflix-to-linux-with-drm) soon(ish).

What is the current state of affairs on the Pi? Does NetfliXBMC work or do we have to wait for further developments?

Comment: You could try [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_1_3) - it might work ok on a Pi

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get Netflix running on OpenELEC but unfortunately the software required isn't free, Netflix used to have an api for developers but they don't any more. The only way I am aware of is to use playon.tv, which has a subscription fee.

If you'd like a tutorial on how to set up Netflix on your Raspberry Pi then checkout [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJFnARZijeI).

Comment: The fact that they don't know that you can control XBMC with your TV remote make me careful, that they use SMB is scary, but they sound reasonably competent otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Nota bene: using payon.tv still requires an Windows PC running for the software and HD is only available if XBMC runs on the very same system. Duh. On the other hand, the solution does not seem to strictly require OpenELEC; as far as I can tell, RaspBMC or any other XBMC installation should work just tone.

Comment: Good point Raphael. It seems I misremember this video, I didn't remember needing to run windows. It still seems to be the best option out there, the only other thing I can think of is running Netflix on your PC and then VNC screen sharing it with your Pi, the frame-rate would be pretty poor but it would at least be free.

Comment: The extra machine (and loss of quality) troubles me more than some dollars, actually. Regarding Windows, I was assuming that; they write only "PC". I could not find any system requirements, so I figured it gotta be Windows.