# Has anyone found a method of streaming netflix to a RaspberryPi (Raspbian, Raspbmc, etc)

Tags: kodi, streaming-video

When this question was asked, the answer was no: [How to stream Netflix on Raspbmc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/how-to-stream-netflix-on-raspbmc)

Howver, Netflix is now available for streaming on Ubuntu while using Google Chrome.  So has anyone leveraged this to make netflix work on any Raspberry Pi OSs?